# Why does the contour plot shows blank part?

Tags: plotting, programming

when I try to plot some complicated functions coming from chi-square distribution, the plot gives me a result with a blank part. I try to narrow the spaced vertical bin using Log for multiple times but the blank part remains.
the function shows as follows, with chi2Dis given by former calculations:

```
chi2Dis=0.542819 (-0.237992 + (1. (x^2 + y^2)^0.28 (1 + 
     1/40 Sqrt[
      x^2 + y^2])^2.66)/((142.325 + (6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - 
       y)^2 - 23.86 Sqrt[(6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - y)^2]
       Cos[0.174048 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] (0.015 + ArcTan[y/x]))/
        Sqrt[(6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - y)^2]])^0.56 (1 + 
     1/40 (142.325 + (6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - y)^2 - 
        23.86 Sqrt[(6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - y)^2]
          Cos[0.174048 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] (0.015 + ArcTan[y/x]))/
           Sqrt[(6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - y)^2]]))^2.66))^2 + 0.542819 (-0.920296 + (1. (x^2 + y^2)^0.28 (1 + 
     1/40 Sqrt[
      x^2 + y^2])^2.66)/((30.1401 + (6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - 
       y)^2 - 10.98 Sqrt[(6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - y)^2]
       Cos[1.16923 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] (0.015 + ArcTan[y/x]))/
        Sqrt[(6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - y)^2]])^0.56 (1 + 
     1/40 (30.1401 + (6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - y)^2 - 
        10.98 Sqrt[(6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - y)^2]
          Cos[1.16923 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] (0.015 + ArcTan[y/x]))/
           Sqrt[(6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - y)^2]]))^2.66))^2 + 0.542819 (-2.61093 + (1. (x^2 + y^2)^0.28 (1 + 
     1/40 Sqrt[
      x^2 + y^2])^2.66)/((42.6409 + (6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - 
       y)^2 - 13.06 Sqrt[(6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - y)^2]
       Cos[1.32055 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] (0.015 + ArcTan[y/x]))/
        Sqrt[(6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - y)^2]])^0.56 (1 + 
     1/40 (42.6409 + (6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - y)^2 - 
        13.06 Sqrt[(6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - y)^2]
          Cos[1.32055 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] (0.015 + ArcTan[y/x]))/
           Sqrt[(6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - y)^2]]))^2.66))^2 + 0.542819 (-3.59972 + (1. (x^2 + y^2)^0.28 (1 + 
     1/40 Sqrt[
      x^2 + y^2])^2.66)/((28.9444 + (6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - 
       y)^2 - 10.76 Sqrt[(6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - y)^2]
       Cos[2.77748 + (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] (0.015 + ArcTan[y/x]))/
        Sqrt[(6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - y)^2]])^0.56 (1 + 
     1/40 (28.9444 + (6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - y)^2 - 
        10.76 Sqrt[(6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - y)^2]
          Cos[2.77748 + (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] (0.015 + ArcTan[y/x]))/
           Sqrt[(6367.9 - x)^2 + (-93. - y)^2]]))^2.66))^2;
ContourPlot[chi2Dis,{x,-15000,25000},{y,-10000,10000},ColorFunction->”Rainbow”]
```

This function might be hard to read but with some other functions the contour plot will still show some blank parts. Does it have constraints to use?

Comment: It probably has to do with the fact that your functions is (almost?) constant... (see `Plot3D[chi2Dis, {x, -150, 250}, {y, -100, 100}]`). Btw., you might want to use `ArcTan[x, y]` instead of `ArcTan[y/x]`...

Comment: @MichaelE2 but you do get a 'blank part' which the question is about :)

Comment: Fabrina, linked topic should answer your question, let me know if you disagree.

Comment: @Kuba Ah, the title is in bigger print, and I've had only about a 0.5 cm of coffee out of my mug....Well, this is dupe, then

Comment: This shows (the logarithm of) the deflection from the maximum at (0,0): http://i.stack.imgur.com/ExZnt.png -- The vertical line is where the function is undefined (divides by zero if `x == 0`, I think) and the small white blotch near the origin is because the value computes to ``0.` `` because of normal floating-point rounding.

Comment: This produces a good-looking plot: `chi2Dis00 = chi2Dis /. y -> 0 /. x -> 0;
ContourPlot[
 SetPrecision[chi2Dis00 - chi2Dis, 32] // Evaluate, {x, -15000, 
  25000}, {y, -10000, 10000}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotRange -> All, ScalingFunctions -> "Log", WorkingPrecision -> 32, 
 Exclusions -> None]`

Comment: A little nicer (tho' Henrik's comment makes me wonder if there's an error): `chi2Dis00 = chi2Dis /. y -> 0 /. x -> 0;
ContourPlot[
 SetPrecision[chi2Dis00 - chi2Dis, 32] // Evaluate, {x, -15000, 
  25000}, {y, -10000, 10000}, Contours -> 10^Range[-16, -3], 
 ColorFunction -> (If[# > 0, 
     ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[Log10[#], {-15.5, -2.5}]], White] &),
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 32, Exclusions -> None, MaxRecursion -> 5, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]` --> http://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnszk.png

Comment: A log view of the poles: `ContourPlot[Log10[chi2Dis], {x, 6315, 6420}, {y, -150, -30}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dbonH.png